# IE7 and IE8 JS support for Math.floor (or some other method?)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've researched around this subject for quite some time but I can't find out which method or code is causing me problems with IE7 and IE8 - it works fine in IE9, Chrome and FF. Using IE9's F12 tools to debug, the javascript stops at this line with the error `object doesn't support this property or method` when running IE7 or IE8 mode:

```
pmt = (Math.floor((princ*intRate)/(1-Math.pow(1+intRate,(-1*months)))*100)/100).toFixed(2);
```

The script is located inline, not via a linked file.

The `pmt` variable is not declared prior to this, and it seems to point to the variable as the problem. Would the script benefit from the variable being declared earlier?

Thanks in advance.

ANSWER:

As per the comment by Cory below, the problem wasn't due to any specific method, but simply my failure to add the `var` declaration before the `pmt` variable.

All sorted now - thanks

Comment: Put in some line breaks and open the IE developer tools (F12) in IE8. You'll get a better idea of the actual location of the error.

Comment: What about testing it? Looks like a bug in IE. Try to split the line into multiple statements for debugging.

Comment: Do you mean "not declared" as in you never use `var` before the `pmt` variable?

Comment: ah, good idea - cheers. will post back shortly.

Comment: yes Cory - could that be the problem?

Comment: The "Math.foo()" methods all work fine in IE in my experience.

Comment: It was the missing `var` before the variable - thanks Cory!

Comment: var is nt necessary.. it will implicitly become a global variable

Comment: Why not create a self-answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its a problem with math.floor or IE take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ULQL/2

May be you are passing in the wrong parameters and the expression is evaluating to something incorrect and hence the error.